# Converting a for loop to use std::transform instead

Tags: c++, for-loop, lambda, stdstring

I'm working on a function and it currently works as is.

```
void ceasarShift( CeasarText& text, int amount ) {
    // Bound amount to the number of characters in the alphabet
    amount %= 26;

    for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < text._originalText.length(); i++ ) {
        char c = text._originalText[i] + amount;
        text._shiftedText += c;
    }
}
```

The class that this function takes is a simple class that has 2 std::string member variables. When this class is passed by reference where this is a friend function to that class, it takes the `original` string that is already set and uses that to populate the `shifted` string which is empty before this function sees it. When the for loop is done, the function is finished and the class object is returned back by reference with a newly updated `shifted` string and the original is unmodified.

I was thinking of maybe using `std::transform` and a `lambda` to do the same task. This is what I have tried.

```
void ceasarShift( CeasarText& text, int amount ) {
    // Bound amount to the number of characters in the alphabet
    amount %= 26;

    /*for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < text._originalText.length(); i++ ) {
        char c = text._originalText[i] + amount;
        text._shiftedText += c;
    }*/

    std::transform( text._originalText.begin(), text._originalText.end(),
                text._shiftedText.begin(),
                [amount]( unsigned char c ) -> unsigned char { return c + amount; }
    );
}
```

And I end up getting a Debug Assertion Failed! Window message `Expression: cannot seek string iterator past end`

I'm wondering if my `lambda` is wrong or if I need to use something else other than `std::transform`.

**Edit**

I have also tried this and this works like the first loop:

```
{
    amount %= 26;

    for ( auto& c : text._originalText )             
        text._shiftedText += (c + amount);

}
```

I just can not seem to get the lambda to work properly as the predicate to `std::transform`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not your lambda. The difference between your two snippets, is that your for loop appends elements to your string, using `operator+=`, but your transform assumes that the elements already exist. If you want to append to the string with transform, then you will need to use an insert iterator. Specifically a back insert iterator. So instead of passing `text._shiftedText.begin()`, pass `std::back_inserter(text._shiftedText)`.

```
std::transform( text._originalText.begin(), text._originalText.end(),
                std::back_inserter(text._shiftedText),
                [amount]( unsigned char c ) -> unsigned char { return c + amount; }
    );
```

Comment: Awesome! I was missing the `back_inserter` that fixed it. Yeah I was scratching my head & thought that the lambda looked right. I've used `transform` on containers before but not too often on strings. Thank You so much!

Answer (score 3):

According to [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/), The behavior of `std::transform` is equivalent to:

```
template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryOperator>
  OutputIterator transform (InputIterator first1, InputIterator last1,
                            OutputIterator result, UnaryOperator op)
{
  while (first1 != last1) {
    *result = op(*first1);  // or: *result=binary_op(*first1,*first2++);
    ++result; ++first1;
  }
  return result;
}
```

which means the container of `OutputIterator` should reserve enough space, otherwise, it will out of range when `++result`

Comment: Thank you for the feed back and this does explain why the debug assertion failure is happening, however, Benjamin Lindley gave the solution to fix the problem. I was using `text._shiftedText.begin()` as the 3rd parameter when I should of been using `std::back_inserter( text._shiftedText )` instead.